Jump to last available page when paginating in Laravel
In Laravel when I use the length aware pagination, let's assume I was on the last page of the data set and I deleted all the records on that page, Laravel will return an empty data set for me since the page query param references the page number for a none existent offset even though there might still be other records available.
UserController.php:
...
$pager = \App\Models\User::paginate(10);

return view('user_list', concat($pager));

user_list.blade.php:
@foreach($pager->data() as $user)
   <div>
      <span>{{$user->name}}</span> &nbsp;
      <a href="{{route ('user.destroy', $user->id)}}">Delete</a>
   </div>
@endforeach

In this case:

How do tell that there are no more records for the current offset/page.
How do I tell if the previous offset/page still contains active records.
How do I elegantly force Laravel to redirect to the previous page without compromising user experience?


You can use the method isEmpty() to check the result and then redirect to last page
    $pager = \App\Models\User::paginate(10);

// Delete records

    if ($pager->isEmpty()) {
    // Redirect to previous page
    return redirect()->to($pager->previousPageUrl());
}

You can also pass the result of $pager->isEmpty() to show message no more records for the current offset/page.

I doubt if the pagination instance has a isEmpty() method, but let me try it out.

It worked, as intended, thank you so much.
